# Constant live update

Tags: android

Does anybody know of a way to have my application constantly check firstly if there is internet connectivity..and secondly if there is internet connection to call a function...It needs to check for internet coverage say every 10 minutes etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to check for network connectivity.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (networkInfo.isConnected())
{
    // do something
}
```

To wake the device every 10 minutes, use the API provided by [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). I don't have practical experience using the AlarmManager; please refer to this [tutorial](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129), which seems fairly comprehensive

Do keep in mind that waking the device this often will have a noticeable effect on battery life.

Comment: I am very new to this, i know about the connectivity manager to check for network, but i dont know about how to do this every ten minutes..What code do i use..thansks

Comment: I've added a link to a pretty good resource for learning to use AlarmManager, since I haven't had occasion to use it myself.

Comment: One other note, getActiveNetworkInfo() CAN return null if there is a RemoteException. So be sure you check if (networkInfo != null) before calling isConnected().